# How to disable LAN access for the wifi users

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I have a wifi router which is connected on the network. The users using the wifi internet can access my LAN network. How to block the wifi users to access my lan network and system. How to configure the wifi users to accesss only the internet and not the LAN.

Comment: See the information here: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/350567-need-to-separate-wifi-from-lan

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your router model (which you didn't mention) you may be able to activate client isolation mode or guest WLAN mode. Alternatively, separate your internal network from the WiFi network by a firewall router.

Comment: Sorry, could u pls explain, my router is Thomson reuterTG585

Comment: I'm not familiar with that model but from the meager documentation I could find online it looks like it does not have any client isolation or guest WLAN features. So either replace it by one that does, or add another router with packet filtering capabilities between it and your internal network.

Comment: Is any way to add separate subnet address to the router.

Comment: Not with the router you have, as far as I can see from the (as I said, not very enlightening) documentation available online.